# Can't update or install plugins locally, macOS

Tags: updates, composer, ssl

I'm unable to update or install plugins in Craft 3.
Running in macOS via MAMP, PHP 7.0.8.

```
Error: The "https://api.github.com/repos/php-fig/cache/zipball/d11b50ad223250cf17b86e38383413f5a6764bf8" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed

Output: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Package operations: 8 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (failed)
Downloading (connecting...)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (connecting...)
Downloading (failed)
```

Has anyone run into this situation or have any suggestions as to how to get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Your local OpenSSL setup is trying to connect with an older, insecure TLS 1.0 protocol, which Github (and a lot of other sites) no longer support.

If you update it to use TLS 1.2, the error will go away.

If you're on something like MAMP/WAMP, etc. then updating to the latest version of their software is usually enough to resolve this issue.

Comment: Yup, after diving through their extensions they don't have OpenSSL listed. Thanks Brad!